# Infinite horizontal scrolling image loop, does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

i created an automatic horizontal slider. In my codepen it worked fine, until I realized that if I widen the screen, it no longer works, it is not continuous but leaves a blank space at the end, then it starts all over again brutally. If I insert a fixed and small width to my css everything works fine, but if I remove it and I want it to be full screen, it gives me this problem. How can I solve? thank you

```css
#prodotti {
  height:350px; 
  width:100%;
  position:relative; 
  overflow:hidden;
}

.photo {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px; 
  left:0px; 
  overflow:hidden; 
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: move 10s linear infinite;
}

.photo img {    
  margin: 0 0.5em 
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
      transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
      transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="prodotti">
  <div id="photo" class="photo">
  
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Now if you see here it works as I want it, but if you try to enlarge the screen or insert it in a full screen page for example 1920px, this is no longer infinite, but it leaves white space.
This is how I see it when it comes to an end.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtUvh.png)

I also accept advice with javascript, like with infinite margins or I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

It works now, also made it responsive

```js
window.onresize = (() => {
  var imgWidth = Math.min(
    window.innerWidth,
    window.innerHeight
  );
  document.getElementById('photo').innerHTML = '';
  for(var i = 0;true;i++) {
    if (
      (document.querySelectorAll('img').length * imgWidth) <
      (window.innerWidth * 2)) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = "https://picsum.photos/200"
      document.getElementById('photo').append(img);
      document.getElementById('photo').append(img);
      document.getElementById('photo').animation = 
      `move ${document.querySelectorAll('img').length / 6}s linear infinite`
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
}

#prodotti {
  height: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.photo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: move 10s linear infinite;
  padding: 0.5vh;
  margin: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.photo img {
  margin: 0 0.5em;
  height: calc(100vh - 16px);
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }
}

@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  .photo img {
    margin-top: calc(50vh - 50vw);
    height: calc(100vw - 16px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="prodotti">
  <div id="photo" class="photo">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="">

  </div>
</div>
```